# Curl GET on CMD line with spaces in file name

Tags: curl, cmd

Trying to download a file through CMD line but I have spaces in the filename preventing the download.

```
curl --request GET -v --user user$site:password https://www.whatever.com/uploads/Filename With Spaces.csv > /users/kanye_west/desktop/FilenameWithSpaces.csv
```

Tried escaping the spaces with backslash `\` already to no avail

Comment: Spaces in url isn't specified as a space. Use the ASCII hex code to specify this. Your URL should be `"https://www.whatever.com/uploads/Filename%20With%20Spaces.csv"`, where `%20` means space.

Comment: a valid URI (RFC3986) cannot contain spaces, but if you enclosed the URL with double quotes it would probably still work....

Comment: @DanielStenberg - even with double quotes, space is not allowed in urls. URLs must be encoded to accommodate space.

Comment: true, but curl will accept a URL with spaces when double quotes are used

Comment: `curl` will pass the space `as is` and web service will not know how to handle the space. Hence the need to encode the spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the URL in quotes.

```
curl --request GET -v --user user$site:password "https://www.whatever.com/uploads/Filename With Spaces.csv" > /users/kanye_west/desktop/FilenameWithSpaces.csv
```

Backslashes would work on Unix, but they aren't used as an escape charater on Windows because they're the original form of directory separator.

Comment: I get a http 400 error when trying.. The command works fine for a file without spaces though

Comment: If the URL were wrong you would get a `404` error. So the problem is probably somewhere else.

Answer (score 5):

Use `%%20` instead of space if it is in the windows batch file. As `%20` in batch file means 20th parameter. So for encoding `%` is used `%%`.

Answer (score 4):

Replace each space by %20

```
curl --request GET -v --user user$site:password https://www.whatever.com/uploads/Filename%20With%20Spaces.csv > /users/kanye_west/desktop/FilenameWithSpaces.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cheap trick to encode urls. It encodes more than just spaces.

```
urlencode() {
    # urlencode <string>

    local length="${#1}"
    for (( i = 0; i < length; i++ )); do
        local c="${1:i:1}"
        case $c in
            [a-zA-Z0-9.~_-:/]) printf "$c" ;;
            *) printf '%%%x' \'"$c" ;;
        esac
    done
}
```

You can then use this function to convert your urls before passing to `curl`.

`curl --request GET -v --user user$site:password $(urlencode "https://www.whatever.com/uploads/Filename With Spaces.csv") > /users/kanye_west/desktop/FilenameWithSpaces.csv`